# How do I access the Express Checkout Details from the response?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal, paypal-sandbox, express-checkout

I am on step 4 of the [implementation guide](https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/expresscheckout/ruby?interactive=OFF&env=sandbox), and so far everything has been pretty cake. My problem now, however, is retrieving user details after they have successfully authenticated with Paypal.

Using the `paypal-sdk-merchant` gem, this is the method fired when a user returns from Paypal after authenticating:

```
def confirm
    @api = PayPal::SDK::Merchant::API.new
    @get_express_checkout_details = @api.build_get_express_checkout_details({:Token => params[:token]})
    @get_express_checkout_details_response = @api.get_express_checkout_details(@get_express_checkout_details)
end
```

The guide (linked to above) states:

```
A response will be returned containing the user's shipping address, the transaction status, and more:

TOKEN=EC-1234567890&ACK=Success&CHECKOUTSTATUS=PaymentActionNotInitiated&EMAIL=user@example.com&...
```

But I can't figure out how to access the returned information, in my view I have tried:

```
<%= @get_express_checkout_details_response.email %>
<%= @get_express_checkout_details_response.Email %>
and
<%= @get_express_checkout_details_response.EMAIL %>
```

but nothing seems to be working. Any ideas?

Comment: Try to binding.pry and see the response and post it here, maybe it is not an object, maybe it is a hash or JSON...

Answer (score 0):

PayPal's gem used SOAP API and return result in corresponding structure - check [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetExpressCheckoutDetails_API_Operation_SOAP/). For example user email - `response.PayerInfo.Payer`, shipping address - `response.PayerInfo.Address`